# $f(x)=f(x-1)+\dfrac{1}{x}$

Tags: functions, functional-equations

I have the $x$th partial sum of the harmonic series, $\sum_{k=1}^{x}{\dfrac{1}{k}}$,
and I want to find a function that is equivalent for integer inputs greater than $0$ so I can take it's derivative which is another question. So what I did is I wrote down the functional equation:

$$f(x)=f(x-1)+\dfrac{1}{x}\;\;\forall x\in \mathbb{N}\setminus\{0,1\}\land f(1)=1$$

I don't even know if such a function exists. I think it might have to do something with an integral of $\dfrac{-1}{x^2}$ or maybe $x$ is a bound of a definite integral.
I tried $\int_{1-x}^{x}\dfrac{-1}{x^2}dx$, but it only adds $\dfrac{1}{x}$ to $\dfrac{1}{x-1}$. I know I can sum the integral over some $k$, but then I am back again where I started.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You function is defined by induction : $f(1)=1$, $f(2)=3/2$, ... so yes it exists

Comment: @SacAndSac I believe OP means a differentiable function  satisfying that condition.

Comment: Look up the digamma function

Comment: @L. F. Yes I want it to be differentiable, that's the whole point

Comment: @Empy2 Wow. Thanks so much. I didn't think it was going to be this easy.